# jQuery/CSS: Sync height between LI (lists) and TD (table) elements in a Custom TreeTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

Example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPVNh/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    sync_height(".title",".row");
    sync_height(".header-label",".row");
});

function sync_height(class1, class2) {
    var h1 = 0, h2 = 0;
    $(class1).each(function(){
        h1 = Math.max($(this).height(), h1);
    });
    $(class2).each(function(){
        h2 = Math.max($(this).height(), h2);
    });
    console.log("Max heights computed: h1="+h1+" h2="+h2);
    if(h1 < h2) { // Set height to the max height encountered 
                  // between the two class elements.
        $(class1).each(function(){
            $(this).height(h2);
        });
    }else{
        $(class2).each(function(){
            $(this).height(h1);
        });
    }
    console.log("Final heights post sync: h1="+
                $(class1).height()+
                " h2="+$(class2).height());
}
```

I've read in many places to use a table's TD properties to align two HTML elements to simulate a panel layout. I could easily use single table where first column represents nested UL/LI tree to create a tree table. But for my app, I need to have a tree table where the list part is an independent div and the cell table part is a separate div. (Additionally there is a multiple-level spanned column header which is represented by another table, and sits on top of the cell Table but this is out of scope for this discussion). Hence I cannot build a tree table in a traditional sense (i.e simulate tree within the table)

My goal is to align the 'rows' between List part (li id="listTree") and the Table part (table id="cellTable"). I'm computing heights in jQuery in the example and syncing heights between LI and TR elements in the widget, but I'm not successful in getting the UL part in sync which is causing "RED" gaps as can be seen on top and bottom of the list (left hand side). Any ideas on how I can sync up the tree and table rows? I'm assuming as long as I do the pixel math right I should be able to sync based on desired dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inline elements such as a `span` won't take up the height expressed in the CSS.

Try adding this to your styling:

```
.header-label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPVNh/1/)

Comment: Thank you! That did it. inline-block elements do seem to take up only the necessary width and height which fits in well with rest of the calculation.